# How can I select preferred languages when I install applications from homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, internationalization

How can I select preferred languages when I install applications from homebrew? Some applications (such as Firefox) have different binary versions for different languages. Is it possible to choose the languages that I prefer most/second most etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `--language`:

```
brew cask install firefox --language=de
```

as pointed out [here](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/doc/cask_language_reference/stanzas/language.md).